# how to loop saving data?

Tags: vba, excel

Here's the situation: In my userform, I have textboxes where the user will input the data and when they hit the save button, the data will be save in excel sheet1.

In sheet1 i will only use 3 rows ("a3:a5") when saving data, meaning when the user hit the save button for the first time the data will be save in "a3" row, when save button hit again for the second time data will be saved in "a4" row, and for the third time data will be save in "a5" row.

What i want to do is when the user hit again the save button (a3:a5 have value) the data will be start saving again in a3 row then to a4 and to a5 repeatedly.

I think looping is the best way for this but i dont know how to do it exactly. Help me please.

here's my sample code, my only problem is the looping process in row ("a3:a5"), a2 row consist of the header

```
Private Sub btnadd_Click()

    Dim stecode As String
    Dim stename As String
    Dim adscode As String
    Dim adsname As String
    Dim added As String

    stecode = TextBox1.Text
    stename = TextBox2.Text
    adscode = TextBox3.Text
    adsname = TextBox4.Text
    added = TextBox5.Text

    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Select
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").Select

    If Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").Offset(1, 0) <> "" Then
        ActiveCell.End(xlDown).Select
    End If

    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    ActiveCell.Value = stecode
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
    ActiveCell.Value = stename
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
    ActiveCell.Value = adscode
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
    ActiveCell.Value = adsname
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
    ActiveCell.Value = added

end sub
```

Comment: Why does the user have to hit the button seperately for each item? Why can they not input the 3 values and hit the save button?

Comment: thanks for the quick response, because i am saving different transactions

Comment: Although it is bad practice to use **ActiveCell**, with what you want to achieve, simply add `If ActiveCell.Row > 5 Then Range("A3").Select`

Comment: yeah ! but how can i replace the value of row "a3" after i select range("a3") if my code basis is " If Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").Offset(1, 0) <> "" "

Answer (score 0):

You can create a private variable to store the row index in the UserForm, then reference that index when writing the values to the worksheet.  The variable can be initialized when the userform is initialized.  After writing the values to the sheet, you can increment the row index and reset it back to 3 after writing in row 5.  See below.

```vb
Option Explicit

Private lRow As Long

Private Sub btnAdd_Click()
    Dim stecode As String
    Dim stename As String
    Dim adscode As String
    Dim adsname As String
    Dim added As String

    stecode = TextBox1.Text
    stename = TextBox2.Text
    adscode = TextBox3.Text
    adsname = TextBox4.Text
    added = TextBox5.Text

    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(lRow, 1).Value = stecode
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(lRow, 2).Value = stename
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(lRow, 3).Value = adscode
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(lRow, 4).Value = adsname
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(lRow, 5).Value = added

    If lRow = 5 Then
        lRow = 3
    Else
        lRow = lRow + 1
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    lRow = 3

End Sub
```

And, you don't even need to declare the string variables if you don't want to.  The `btnAdd` routine can be written more compactly as:

```vb
Private Sub btnAdd_Click()

    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        .Cells(lRow, 1).Value = TextBox1.Text
        .Cells(lRow, 2).Value = TextBox2.Text
        .Cells(lRow, 3).Value = TextBox3.Text
        .Cells(lRow, 4).Value = TextBox4.Text
        .Cells(lRow, 5).Value = TextBox5.Text
    End With

    If lRow = 5 Then
        lRow = 3
    Else
        lRow = lRow + 1
    End If

End Sub
```

`Option Explicit` is used to force explicit declaration of all variables in the module.  I think it's good practice and it can reduce data type errors.  You can read more [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg278855(v=office.14).aspx).

Comment: awesome ! that's what im talking about,exactly :) but can you explain further about option explicit ?

Comment: i have last question, can I specify the row and cell where to save the data ? like for example is in "F4".Thanks man

Comment: @Istian: What data do you want to save in F4?

Comment: for "F4", simply replaces `.cells` with `.range`.  if textbox1 (and the following) are correctly set, you can loop them by refering to them as `Me.controls("Textbox" & i).text` , where `Me` is the userform, and `i` an incrementing loop variable...

Comment: also, avoid usind `.select` and `.activate`, it will slow down speed enourmously, and can even trigger Worksheet_Selection_Change events (in some case causing infinite loop), (can be avoided by `application.enableevents=false`, don't forget to reinitialise to true later).